# Youtube API User History (Playlistitems) without Authorization

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to retrieve the watch history data of my own Youtube account using the Youtube Javascript API. I am using the auth.js listed **[here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript)**.

I have made everything work, but it requires authorization (website asks you to login with a Google account so other people cannot view what i'm displaying without logging into my Youtube account).

I'm looking for a way for a website to display my Youtube history data without authorization. Reading similar questions here and googling seems to suggest that it's not possible with just **Google Client API**. If anyone knows a way to do this or where I should look for, please let me know. I'm new to web stuff so any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: no, it's not impossible: you can simply give eveyone your password. or you can hit the API with your own php server that keep secrets, and have everyone else talk to the php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple answer: **It can not do without Authorization**
You can do that in different way

after Authorization you can sync your youtube history with another database and show that data from fetching from that database to others